# Is there this endpoint address within Web.config file and WSDL soap:address within wsdl file should be same or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

This is my `web.config`:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://ogr-cust-w01:90/Cust2024.asmx"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Cust2024MenuSoap"
              contract="Cust2024_DEVL.Cust2024MenuSoap" name="CustMenuSoap" />
</client>
```

This is my WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:service name="Cust2024Menu">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Cust2024DataAccess</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port name="CustMenuSoap" binding="tns:CustMenuSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.cust.com:70/Cust2024.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="Cust2024MenuSoap12" binding="tns:Cust2024MenuSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.cust.com:70/Cust2024.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

The `web.config` file specifies an address with `http://org-cust-w01:90/Cust2024.asmx` while the WSDL specifies addresses with `http://www.cust.com:70/Cust2024.asmx` for
`Cust2024_DEVL.Cust2024MenuSoap`.

Should the endpoint address in `web.config` and WSDL soap:address not be same?

Error: I got the error log

> There was no endpoint listening at http://org-cust-w01:90/Cust2024.asmx that could accept the message.
> This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Your code is using Ports 70 and 90 and these ports may be blocked.  Port numbers under 1000 are usually reserved for standard protocols and port numbers above 1000 are usually user defined protocols.  Many virus checkers can block protocols that use ports under 1000.  You error message is a generally error message indicating the connection was blocked or did not complete.  Many servers will have frontend code that checks port numbers and return error messages when a Protocol is not allowed.

Comment: You are getting an error "There was no endpoint listening".  A lot of servers return confusing error messages to make it hard for hackers to attach the server.  Your error message could occur for two different reasons.  1) The server returned the error message after connection completed but the protocol was not allowed.  2) The client returned the error message when trying to connect to a server and a timeout occurred meaning the connection never completed.

Comment: Thank you  @jdweng for your response.  how to I fix it and my question is [ Is there this endpoint address with in web.config and WSDL soap:address should be same or not? ]

Comment: Every Server is different.  I do not know what ports the server is using and the routes that are configured.  In your case "http://www.cust.com:70" is the endpoint 
 and "/Cust2024.asmx" is a route.

Comment: How to I fix this issue? @jdweng , Please give some ideas

Comment: You have to get the server documentation.